# Can't cross-compile simple kernel module

Tags: linux-kernel

I'm trying to compile following 'Hello World'.

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("BOBR");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("HELLO MODULE");
MODULE_VERSION("0.10");

static char *name = "user";
module_param(name, charp, S_IRUGO);
MODULE_PARM_DESC(name, "The name to display");

static int __init hello_init(void) {
    printk(KERN_INFO "HEllo, %s!\n", name);
    return 0;
}
static void __exit hello_exit(void) {
    printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye, %s !\n", name);
}

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);
```

My Makefile is

```
ifneq ($(KERNELRELEASE),)
include Kbuild
#KDIR ?= ../repos/linux 
else
    KDIR ?= /lib/modules/4.9.0-6-amd64/build

default:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$$PWD

clean:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$$PWD clean

endif
```

I start make as: `make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE='ccache arm-eabi-' PATH=/opt/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_arm-eabi/bin:$PATH`

I compile on Debian 4.9.0-6-amd64. Target is arm32 4.16.18.
The problem is that I get a module for my host machine (I can insmod it), but the target kernel rejects it as invalid module.

When I try to change the linux path in the Makefile to the target kernel sources, the compilation fails with `fatal error: asm/barrier.h: No such file or directory`.

Comment: You should pass `ARCH` and `CROSS_COMPILE` parameters to **inner make invocation** (`make -C ... M=...`). Exactly this invocation builds the module with kernel build system.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks, but now it says 'Could not find compiler "arm-eabi-gcc-6" in PATH'.

Comment: Oh, you should set *PATH* as **environment variable**, not as `make` *parameter*. `PATH=<...> make <...>`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev It worked, thanks!

Comment: And for everyone who may read it - don't forget to 'make clean' after unsuccessful attempts)